# How to know programmatically whether application runs in client or cluster deploy mode using YARN?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

Is it possible to know programmatically in which mode a Spark program is running? For example, whether it is running in `yarn-cluster` or `yarn-client` mode?

Comment: I think it was before Spark 2 and there is no `yarn-client` and `yarn-cluster` anymore --> https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/resource-managers/yarn/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/scheduler/cluster/YarnClusterManager.scala#L34-L35

Comment: Well its deprecated, but one can still use it. Now instead of --master yarn-cluster, one would write --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster, for example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`deployMode`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext@deployMode:String) method of the `SparkContext`

```
val sc: SparkContext = ???
sc.deployMode
```

If you use `SparkSession` you have to access `SparkContext` instance first:

```
val spark: SparkSession = ???
spark.sparkContext.deployMode
```

You can of course combine it with `master` call, to get a full picture:

```
sc.master
```